# Question from a Visual Basic 2008 Beginner about Arrays

Tags: visual-studio-2008, arrays

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk09p.png

Here is a screenshot of my code, the array "Array" is declared globally  I'm having problems finding the highest and lowest values in the array.  When the value is returned to the label controls, it always displays a 0 and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember how strictly typed VB is, but when you're adding the value to the array you're using ToString to cast it to a string first. Later on you're then declaring intLargest as an integer and assigning one of the array values (now a string) to it.